# Use the Transform operator to remove one or more key/value pairs from an Object?

Tags: jsonata

JSONata newbie checking in. I have reviewed all the questions in this forum and cannot find the answer so am asking here.

Given this source...

```
{
  "Price": 34.45,
  "Product Name": "Bowler Hat",
  "ProductID": 858383,
  "Quantity": 2,
  "SKU": "0406654608"
}
```

I would like to reduce it to...

```
{
  "Product Name": "Bowler Hat",
  "ProductID": 858383,
  "SKU": "0406654608"
}
```

...using the [Transform](https://docs.jsonata.org/other-operators#-------transform) operator to delete Price and Quantity. I've tried various permutations of this...

```
$ ~> |*|{}, ['Price', 'Quantity']|
```

..but am not getting the result I am looking for. [Here](https://try.jsonata.org/0953T_8u4) is an Exerciser link.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small modification needed - the 'matching' clause needs to match the object that you wish to modify, in your case it is the context item '$'.  The wildcard '*' is going to return the sequence of values in that object rather than the object itself.  So your expression should be:

```
$ ~> |$|{}, ['Price', 'Quantity']|
```

See https://try.jsonata.org/qUwOtT-pt